# Is it possible to create constraint with usage of regex in Neo4j?

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher, constraints

I would like to ask you if it is possible to create constraint in Neo4j(cypher) with the usage of regex.
To be specific, I have lot of nodes which serves as IPs and I would like to ensure, that each node(property ip_address) is having proper format for IP address.
If the answer is no, is there any workaround ? The only one which currently comes to my mind, is to check every node in programming language before adding them to Neo4j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't currently available in an easy-to-apply constraint form.

While the recommended approach when you need specific formatting is to handle this at the application layer, you could create a trigger that could check if a newly-added node of the given label has the correct formatting and fail out if not.

This does take some additional work and testing however.

[TransactionEventHandlers](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/transactions/#transactions-events) are used to implement this. Here's the [TransactionEventHandler java interface](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html) you'll need to implement.

Alternately you can use [triggers in APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers) to implement this with Cypher.